# Confirming more than one email in Asp.net Identity core

Tags: asp.net-identity

I have a use case where I need to confirm two email Ids for the same user. In asp.net core we have the in-built GenerateChangeEmailTokenAsync and ConfirmEmailAsync methods which can be used to confirm one email Id.

Is there a way I can additionally confirm one more ? I searched the net but was unable to find any reference.

I know I might have to extend the aforementioned methods for this. But is there a simpler way to do this so that I can use the existing identity framework extensions to achieve my use case?

Comment: Why not just call it twice?

Comment: I am not sure, but i guess the token generated is against the primary email id every time. I have an additional email field and a email confirmed field that needs to be set, I am currently thinking of using GenerateUserTokenAsync method for this second email. it seems to be working but then I might have to end up doing the token life cycle management at my end.

Comment: I don't think the default Identity framework is designed to handle such a case where a user can have 2 e-mail addresses. May I ask, out of curiosity, what is the use case in your application?

Comment: I am using identity server 4 to authenticate my users using facebook, now facebook can deny consent for  email, so i need to provide option for user to manually enter the email (this will be for communication). Then comes the company email id which is to verify that the user belong to the the company in question, I could have used this for communication but dont want to spam their official mail box...hence the necessity to maintain two emails one for company verification and the other for communication purpose...

Comment: Okay, I'm starting to get the picture. So, if a user denies sharing their e-mail address, you then say 'Fine, you don't have to share your e-mail through Facebook, but you must give me a valid e-mail address. And you must also validate your company e-mail.' But this goes against Facebook's own view on how you need to handle declined permissions. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/handling-declined-permissions in particular the section on denying the e-mail grant.

Comment: After all, how beneficial is it, to validate the e-mail address of the user, considering they have signed up through Facebook as the identity provider. If the user didn't grant his e-mail, and then fills in a bogus e-mail because you require it, the result would be the same as just saying 'okay, we won't communicate with you.'. I would set the company e-mail address as the main email to be validated. Because from what you have told, looks like that's the most important one.

Comment: Agreed ! I have set the company email id as the main email id without which the user cannot login. but there is also another scenario, even lets say the user accepts to share  the  email id coming from facebook what is the guarantee that its still there, one could have deleted it...also I need to provide the option to update these email ids later

Comment: yup I am prompting the user on why we require the email id, as per the fb guidelines. but its still not a mandatory thing for my login process :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented the multiple email verification like this : Email is the primary email that identity core handles, I have an additional LoginEmail added to the ApplicationUser
Generating Email Tokens :

```
if (!user.EmailConfirmed)
                    {
                        //send token for email confirmation 
                        var token = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                        var confirmationLink = Url.Action(nameof(ConfirmEmail), "Account", new { token, id = user.Id, email = user.Email }, Request.Scheme);

                        var message = new EmailMessage(user.Email, "Confirmation email link", confirmationLink);
                        await _emailService.SendMail(message);

                    }

                    if (!user.LoginEmailConfirmed)
                    {
                        var token1 = await _userManager.GenerateUserTokenAsync(user, "Default", "Confirmation");
                        var confirmationLoginEmailLink = Url.Action(nameof(ConfirmEmail), "Account", new { token = token1, id = user.Id, email = user.LoginEmail, }, Request.Scheme);

                        var message = new EmailMessage(user.LoginEmail, "Confirmation email link", confirmationLoginEmailLink);
                        await _emailService.SendMail(message);
                    }
```

The Confirming part : First I check if the email to confirm is LoginEmail then I use the VerifyUserTokenAsync method to verify the token

```
if (user.LoginEmail == email)
        {
            var confirmationResult = await _userManager.VerifyUserTokenAsync(user, "Default", "Confirmation", token);
            if (confirmationResult)
            {
                user.LoginEmailConfirmed = true;
                var updateResult = await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
                return View(updateResult.Succeeded ? nameof(ConfirmEmail) : "Error", new ConfirmEmailViewModel() { EmailConfirmed = user.EmailConfirmed, LoginEmailConfirmed = user.LoginEmailConfirmed, LoginUrl = _config.Value.ClientUrl });
            }
            else
            {
                return View("Error");
            }
        }
        else {
            var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, token);
            return View(result.Succeeded ? nameof(ConfirmEmail) : "Error", new ConfirmEmailViewModel() { EmailConfirmed = user.EmailConfirmed, LoginEmailConfirmed = user.LoginEmailConfirmed, LoginUrl = _config.Value.ClientUrl });
        }
```